# the paging of Grid.MVC not work

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, gridview, kendo-grid

Im using Grid.MVC in my MVC web application 
When test it in a blank page with index controller it works successfully with pagination and filtration.
The Problem accrue when i put it in my project
the steps that i do that i make ajax request (because i don't need to reload the page) to method and return a partial view that contains the result of the search by the Grid.Mvc the result and number of pages return successfully but when i press to next page or filter it doesn't work.

Code:

View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Home",
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "SearchResult"
        })){
@Html.DropDownList("Province", "Province")
@Html.DropDownList("Cities", "Cities")
<span>price from :</span>    <input type="text" name="Pricefrom" />
<span>to :</span>           <input type="text" name="Priceto" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />      }
```

Search Controller :

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(int? page , int Province = 0, int Cities = 0, int Pricefrom = 0, int Priceto = 0)
    {
        var ads = db.Ad.Where(a => (Cities == 0 || a.CityId == Cities) &&
                                   (Province == 0 || a.Cities.ProvinceId == Province)&&
                                   (Pricefrom == 0 || a.Price >= Pricefrom)&&
                                   (Priceto == 0 || a.Price <= Priceto)).OrderBy(a => a.AdDate).ToList();

        return PartialView("_Search", ads);
    }
```

PartialView:

```
@using GridMvc.Html
@model IEnumerable<Semsark.Areas.Backend.Models.Ad>
<div>
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Add(c => c.Id).Titled("ID");
            columns.Add(c => c.AdTitle).Titled("title");
            columns.Add(c => c.AdBody).Titled("body");
        }).WithPaging(2).Sortable(true)
</div>
```

scripts and styles in the View index.cshtml :

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Gridmvc.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/gridmvc.min.js")"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/gridmvc.lang.ru.js"></script>
<title>Index</title>
```

Thanks in advance for any help,

Comment: are you using Grid.Mvc.Ajax package ?

Answer (score 1):

```
@*Webgrid using Paging in mvc 4.

View Page **.cshtml**  *@

    @model MvcPopup.Models.PagedEmployeeModel

    @{
        //ViewBag.Title = "SearchEmployee";
        Layout = null;
    }

    @{
        WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize);
        grid.Bind(Model.Employee,
                  autoSortAndPage: false,
                  rowCount: Model.TotalRows
        );
    }

    @grid.GetHtml(
        fillEmptyRows: false,
        alternatingRowStyle: "alternate-row",
        headerStyle: "grid-header",
        footerStyle: "grid-footer",
        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
                firstText: "<< First",
                previousText: "< Prev",
                nextText: "Next >",
                lastText: "Last >>",
        columns: new[] {


            grid.Column("Name",
                        header: "Name",
                        format: @<text>
                            @Html.ActionLink((string)item.Name, "ViewEmployeeDetail", new { id = item.id }, new { @class = "viewDialog" })</text>
                        ),
            grid.Column("Department"),
             grid.Column("City"),
              grid.Column("State"),
           grid.Column("Country",
                        header: "Country"
            ),
             grid.Column("Mobile"),
            grid.Column("",
                        header: "Actions",
                        format: @<text>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditEmployee", new { id = item.id }, new { @class = "editDialog" })
                            |

                            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.id }, new { @class = "confirmDialog"})
                        </text>
            )
    })

@*-----------------------------------
Model folder under modelservices.cs file
=================================*@

    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployeePage(int pageNumber, int pageSize, string searchCriteria)
            {
                if (pageNumber < 1)
                    pageNumber = 1;

                return db.Employees 
                    .OrderBy(m =>m.Name)
                  .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
                  .Take(pageSize)
                  .ToList();
            }
             public int CountAllEmployee()
            {
                return db.Employees.Count();
            }
            public class PagedEmployeeModel
        {
            public int TotalRows { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
            public int PageSize { get; set; }
        }

@*Controller folder under create file like employeecontroller.cs *@

    using MvcPopup.Models;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Text;

    namespace MvcPopup.Controllers
    {
        public class EmployeeController : Controller
        {
            //
            // GET: /Employee/
            ModelServices mobjModel = new ModelServices();
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }
            public ActionResult SearchEmployee(int page = 1, string sort = "name", string sortDir = "ASC")
            {
                const int pageSize = 5;
                var totalRows = mobjModel.CountAllEmployee(); 

                sortDir = sortDir.Equals("desc", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? sortDir : "asc";

                var validColumns = new[] { "id", "name", "department", "country" };
                if (!validColumns.Any(c => c.Equals(sort, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
                    sort = "id";

                var employee = mobjModel.GetEmployeePage(page, pageSize, "it." + sort + " " + sortDir);

                var data = new PagedEmployeeModel()
                {
                    TotalRows = totalRows,
                    PageSize = pageSize,
                    Employee = employee
                };
                return View(data);
            }
    ------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to pass through an IQueryable list instead of an IEnumerable? According to the documentation, Gridmvc.Html requires an IQueryable for paging. There are some subtle differences between IQueryable and IEnumerable that might make a difference here.

Answer (score 0):

These scripts are needed for paging:

```
 "~/Scripts/GridMvc/URI.js"
 "~/Scripts/GridMvc/gridmvc.min.js"
 "~/Scripts/GridMvc/gridmvc-ext.js"
```